# How to optimize and remake my text converter (works really slow)

Tags: python

Here is and example of code

```
for i in quoteAuthor:
if i == " ": quoteAuthorToMN += " "
if i == ",": quoteAuthorToMN += ","
if i == ".": quoteAuthorToMN += "."
if i == "К": quoteAuthorToMN += "ᠺ‍"
if i == "Э": quoteAuthorToMN += "ᠡ"
if i == "И": quoteAuthorToMN += "ᠢ"
if i == "Я": quoteAuthorToMN += "ᠢ"
if i == "Ь": quoteAuthorToMN += "ᠢ"
if i == "О": quoteAuthorToMN += "ᠣ"
if i == "У": quoteAuthorToMN += "ᠤ"
if i == "Ө": quoteAuthorToMN += "ᠥ"
if i == "Ү": quoteAuthorToMN += "ᠦ"
```

...

I have to make it faster somehow, help me. And show me how to use normal and fast way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a dictionary in this fashion:

```
letters = { "y": "ᠤ", "Ө": "ᠥ",  ... }
```

Then just iterate:

```
new_quote = ""
for i in len(quoteAuthor):
    new_quote += letters[quoteAuthor[i]]
```

A more efficient way could be:

```
new_quote = ''.join([letters[quoteAuthor[i]] for i in range(len(quoteAuthor))])
```

Comment: Since [str is immutable](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/CS152f17/Strings/StringsareImmutable.html) the first solution probably won't work. Also, welcome on stackoverflow!

Comment: True! Forgot about that, I edited my answer thanks!

Comment: Note that this answer is rather inefficient because each `+=` operation on a string results in a new copy of the string since strings are immutable. You should map the characters to a list first, and then use the `str.join` method to generate a new string in one shot. Refer to the linked question for a better solution.

Comment: True, added an improved solution using this, thanks!